# Looking for a way to stop forcing my app into full screen when admob interstitial is shown

Tags: android, admob

I implemented admob interstitials into my app and everything is working fine.

Admobs interstitials are full screen and this is fine, the problem is that somehow when the admob interstitial is shown in full screen, my app (in the background) also jumps into full screen.

Now when someone closes the ad, the app jumps from full screen back to being normal again and this looks like a bug to me, because it causes a small flickering effect.

Did anyone else notice this effect, or I am alone in this?

Is there some way to fix this? Can i force my app to stay that way and not jump to full screen? Or can I  force the status bar on interstitials ads?

Thank in advance!

Edit, my sourcecode is very similiar to this (standard approach taken from google itself):

```
public class BannerExample extends Activity {

  private InterstitialAd interstitial;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

  }

  // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

update:
i integrated mopub which also offers full screen interstitials and interestingly enough this does not happen with mopub even though integrating it in the app is similar to admob. so i bet this is some odd behaviour of admob and not some bug in my app

Comment: Some screenshots and code may help.

Comment: I see this too, you are not alone

Comment: interesting ... at least i am not alone, but i guess no waz to "fix" this :-(

Comment: i integrated mopub which also offers full screen interstitials and interestingly enough this does not happen with mopub even though integrating it in the app is similar to admob. so i bet this is some odd behaviour of admob and not some bug in my app

Comment: You are right.I think admob interstitial implementation has some problem. It's causing my custom view to change size. While at the same time FAN interstitial is not producing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It really depend on what is going on during Activity.onResume, when it call resume it try to update the view. It may look like flickering, but it just updating the view.  Check your class and print some debug log to see what is it doing when you click the close button.

AdMob SDK don't control your class, so it only dismiss the ad view. What you do in your class cause the flickering. Without seeing the code, I cannot say for sure, maybe some code would be great.

Comment: i use the standard approach taken from google. i dont have anything onResume, thats why i am puzzled to why the flickering effect is happening

Comment: It is standard, you may not have the method in your class but your parent class do have onStop(), onPause(), onRestarts(), onStart(). Override it and add some debug log, when the view leave foreground or not visible, then enter foreground again it will call on those method.

Comment: i integrated mopub which also offers full screen interstitials and interestingly enough this does not happen with mopub even though integrating it in the app is similar to admob. so i bet this is some odd behaviour of admob and not some bug in my app

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working with another ad provider. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check my reply here:

[Phonegap screen flickers with AdMob animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934313/phonegap-screen-flickers-with-admob-animation)

Perhaps is a similar issue. Not every developer has the luxury of switching to a different provider (ie. if you work with a client)